# How do I pass options to the Selenium Chrome driver using Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The [Selenium documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) mentions that the Chrome webdriver can take an instance of `ChromeOptions`, but I can't figure out how to create `ChromeOptions`.

I'm hoping to pass the `--disable-extensions` flag to Chrome.

Answer (score 150):

Found the [chrome Options class in the Selenium source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.py).

Usage to create a Chrome driver instance:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: This answer was a lifesaver.  In case it's useful to others, to enable ES6 Harmony features, the call is `chrome_options.add_argument("--js-flags=--harmony")`

Comment: Note: `chrome_options` arg is now deprecated in favor of the simpler `options`, e.g.: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Comment: Hey, @k107 I was wondering If I can do the same thing except for one change. Can I use `chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-extensions")` to enable all **extensions** instead of adding each extension manually by (code)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

This is how I did it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 7):

Code which disable chrome extensions for ones, who uses [**DesiredCapabilities**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) to set browser flags :

```
desired_capabilities['chromeOptions'] = {
    "args": ["--disable-extensions"],
    "extensions": []
}
webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-logging')

# Update your desired_capabilities dict withe extra options.
desired_capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Both the **desired_capabilities** and **options.to_capabilities()** are dictionaries. You can use the **dict.update()** method to add the **options** to the main set.

Answer (score 3):

**If you use regular chromedriver:**

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def main():
    # Set the path to the chromedriver
    chromedriver_path = "path/to/chromedriver"

    # Create ChromeOptions
    options = Options()

    # Your Options here....
    # options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode
    # options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU acceleration

    # Create a ChromeDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=options)

    # Open Website
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")

    # your code.. clicking on buttons etc..

    # Close the ChromeDriver
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**If you use undetected chromedriver:**

```
pip3 install undetected-chromedriver
```

Example code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


def main():
    # Set the path to the chromedriver executable
    chromedriver_path = "path/to/chromedriver"

    # Create options object
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()

    # Add options if needed
    # options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode
    # options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU acceleration

    # Create an instance of Undetected ChromeDriver with options
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=options)

    try:
        # Open Google
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")

        # Rest of your code for interacting with the Google page

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    finally:
        # Close the ChromeDriver
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Here some of the chrome options I use regularly:**

```
    options.add_argument(f"--window-size=1366,768")
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--enable-automation")
    options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")

    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=PATH_TO_CHROME_PROFILE")
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=IP_ADRESS:PORT')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it as I needed a matching version of the Chrome. First, make sure you install a supported version of the Chrome. Go to the webdriver page and mark the latest supported version of your chrome. Then run (replace with your version)

```
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@114.0.5735.90
```

Then, install the auto-installer and the following should work out of the box:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("Page title was '{}'".format(driver.title))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```