# Prevent Selenium from taking the focus to the opened window

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I have 40 Python unit tests and each of them open a Selenium driver as they are separate files and cannot share the same driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Firefox()
```

The above commands will take the focus to the new opened window. For example, if I am on my editor and typing something, in the middle of my work, suddenly a selenium browser is opening and Linux switch to that window. I am not sure if Windows or Mac have a similar problem or not.

This means that every time I run a unit, I cannot use my computer as it keeps switching away from the application that I am currently using.

How can I tell Selenium not to switch to the opened window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: How to stop the browser window getting on-top for every get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741089/selenium-how-to-stop-the-browser-window-getting-on-top-for-every-get)

Comment: Afaik there isn't a `start_minimized()` method for Selenium. You could run it headless tho, and that won't steal focus.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, would you please explain your answer? I don't see anything [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py).

Comment: What do you mean, @ar2015 - are you unfamiliar with headless mode in Firefox/python? You want me to pen down a quick example?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, yes please. I ran `driver.minimize_window()` no success. `driver.start_minimized()`  also does not exist. If can minimize, that will be even better so if it fails, I can see where the problem shows up.

Comment: This is what I wrote above, that such method does **not** exist in Selenium (as opposed to `maximize_window()`, which exists). However, you can run the browser in headless mode. Would you like an example?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of running Selenium/Firefox on linux, in headless mode. You can see various imports as well - gonna leave them there. Browser will start in headless mode, will go to ddg page and print out the page source, then quit.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1280")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=720")
firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver') ## path where geckodriver is

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

browser.get('https://duckduckgo.com')
print(browser.page_source)
browser.quit()
```

Browser can also take screenshots while in headless mode, if any unit test requires it.

A reasonably well structured documentation for Selenium can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ (with some gaps, of course, but generally decent).

Answer (score 2):

You can run your Selenium drivers in headless mode. This will prevent moving focus on opened by Selenium browsers and will not disturb you working on your PC machine.