# Python - Remote Webdriver with Extension installed in it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, remotewebdriver

I want to test one extension on different browser versions using [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com).
This is a function that returns driver with specified capabilities.
I have a `.crx file` for Chrome and an `.xpi file` for Firefox on my local machine.
I want to use `Remote Webdriver` with a corresponding extension installed, using Python.

```
def my_webdriver(browser, browser_version, os, os_version):
    caps = {}
    caps["browser"] = browser
    caps["browser_version"] = browser_version
    caps["os"] = os
    caps["os_version"] = os_version
    caps["browserstack.debug"] = "true"
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
    ¦   command_executor = 'blahblahblah',
    ¦   desired_capabilities = caps)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver
```

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, you need to create a profile and add your extension to it using [`add_extension`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile.add_extension). Then you pass the profile to the WebDriver constructor:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
...
fp = FirefoxProfile()
fp.add_extension('/path/to/your/extension.xpi')
driver = RemoteWebDriver(..., browser_profile=fp)
```

Alternatively, you can create a Firefox profile in advance, and manually add your extenstion to it. Later you pass its path as parameter to `FirefoxProfile()`

```
fp = FirefoxProfile('/path/to/your/profile')
```

For Chrome, use [`ChromeOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698844):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('/path/to/your/extension.crx')
driver = RemoteWebDriver(..., desired_capabilities = caps + chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

Comment: When I try it with Chrome, I get this exception: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'` when running `desired_capabilities=caps + chrome_options.to_capabilities()`.

Answer (score 0):

[E.Z.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21850504/1587329) for chrome works if you use `caps.update`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension('/path/to/your/extension.crx')
caps.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())
driver = RemoteWebDriver(..., desired_capabilities=caps)
```