# Selenium Firefox webdriver does not adopt profile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have created a FF profile:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", CLIENT_SAVING_DIR)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
```

Then pass this profile to remote mode webdriver:

```
remoteHost="192.168.x.y:4444/wd/hub"
driver = webdriver.Remote(remoteHost, 
                              desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, 
                              browser_profile=pf)
```

I've downgraded my Firefox to version 35.0 and using Selenium `selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar`.

The driver works just fine but it seems the profile I had set is not used. The browser still appears the download prompt dialog.

I have tried for many times and consult everything I could find. Even tried playing with `about:config` in FireFox but useless.
Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. (It took me for a day at work)

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
... set your profile attributes
fp.update_preferences() #the answer
```

I think it's important to paste this line at the end of profile definition. Selenium API should put this line into their documentation.

Comment: Ooop! My typo, it's fp (FirefoxProfile instance)

Comment: AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'update_preference'

Comment: Change last method name to `update_preferences` to make it work