# Downloading with chrome headless and selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I'm using python-selenium and Chrome 59 and trying to automate a simple download sequence. When I launch the browser normally, the download works, but when I do so in headless mode, the download doesn't work.

```
# Headless implementation
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)

driver.get('https://www.mockaroo.com/')
driver.find_element_by_id('download').click()
# ^^^ Download doesn't start
```

---

```
# Normal Mode
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.mockaroo.com/')
driver.find_element_by_id('download').click()
# ^^^ Download works normally
```

---

I've even tried adding a default path:

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/Users/Chetan/Desktop/"}
chromeOptions.add_argument("headless")
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
```

Adding a default path works in the normal implementation, but the same problem persists in the headless version.

How do I get the download to start in headless mode?

Comment: I've also tried using `submit` and sending `Keys.ENTER`. It works for the normal browser,but not the headless one.

Comment: do you want it to be done using chrome only?? or firefox also would do?

Comment: Prefer chrome or phantomjs

Comment: Why not just use urllib to download the file? clicking on the file to simulate downloading only counts for some of the user cases. Ive used browsers where it opens a "save as" window before it starts downloading. If you are clicking to see if it exists on server, or to verify the contents of the file, urllib is probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: @TehTris the problem is, I'm doing this on another site that requires me to have logged in earlier. That sets both headers and cookies, so I need to set both before using it. But using just js, there seems to be no way to get the request headers from the client side... So I can't use urlllib

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599776/download-file-through-google-chrome-in-headless-mode/57606294#57606294) helps you?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode (in 2021). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

They later renamed the option in 2023 for Chrome 109 -> https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4

For Chrome 109 and above, the `--headless=new` flag will now allow you to get the full functionality of Chrome in the new headless mode, and you can even run extensions in it. (For Chrome versions 96 through 108, use `--headless=chrome`)

Usage: (Chrome 109 and above):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Usage: (Chrome 96 through Chrome 108):

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=chrome")
```

If something works in regular Chrome, it should now work with the newer headless mode too.

Comment: I just edited my existing solution because in 2023 for Chrome 109, they renamed the previous option from `--headless=chrome` to `--headless=new`.

Comment: Tested today, it worked.

Comment: This is freaking magical ;)

Comment: FWIW, this is now officially announced as shipping in Chrome 112: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/ Please report any bugs you run into so we can fix them!

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day. Till 108 version, even `--headless` worked for me.

Comment: `--headless=new` worked fine

Comment: I'm on 121 and none of them work... Why do they want to change this every week? It seems like now you have to do `options.headless = True`

Comment: Nevermind. Nothing works. Not `options.headless = True` Not `--headless=new`, not `--headless=chrome`, not `--headless=old`, not `--headless`. This is absolutely ridiculous

Answer (score 63):

Yes, it's a "feature", for security. As mentioned before here is the bug discussion: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

Support was added in chrome version 62.0.3196.0 or above to enable downloading.

Here is a python implementation. I had to add the command to the chromedriver commands. I will try to submit a PR so it is included in the library in the future.

```
def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(self, driver, download_dir):
    # add missing support for chrome "send_command"  to selenium webdriver
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

For reference here is a little repo to demonstrate how to use this:
https://github.com/shawnbutton/PythonHeadlessChrome

*update 2020-05-01* There have been comments saying this is not working anymore. Given this patch is now over a year old it's quite possible they have changed the underlying library.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work for me :( When I try exactly like that, I get nothing, and when I just turn off the "headless" mode, I get the file, but then Chrome crashes. If I completely remove the code from this answer together with the headless mode, Chrome works like expected. I guess Chrome's API has changed?

Comment: @bitstream It worked for me on **Chromium 68.0.3440.75** & **chromedriver 2.38**, [check my full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725319/2733526)

Comment: @shawn-button how download videos..seems HTML5 videos play on chrome by default

Comment: You said that Support was added in chrome version 62.0.3196.0 or above to enable downloading. But I am currently working with Chrome 71 but it does not work there either. The same workaround process need to be followed..

Comment: I am getting the error:  -`"Download failed: Path too long"` while using the above solution. I am using version 73 and Python

Comment: does this still up to date? I tried the method in the github, it doesn't download file. I tested the code can download file when not in headless mode. the print out shows: response from browser:
result:value:None

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium/66484833#66484833) is a working and updated solution. Still working 11/5/21.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a working example for Python based on [Shawn Button's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366981/2733526). I've tested this with **Chromium 68.0.3440.75** & **chromedriver 2.38**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "/path/to/download/dir",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': "/path/to/download/dir"}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

driver.get('http://download-page.url/')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#download_link").click()
```

Comment: Also be careful that element target is not set to "_blank" otherwise switching tab and trying to download the file won't work

Comment: Thanks for posting. I also needed to add ```chromedriver_location = "/path/to/chromedriver"```, and then reference that in the driver definition, i.e. ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location,options=chrome_options)```
sidenote: the ```chrome_options``` param is deprecating soon, and is already replaced with the ```options``` param, as demonstrated in my little example here.

Answer (score 18):

This is a feature of Chrome to prevent from software to download files to your computer. There is a workaround though. [Read more about it here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481).

What you need to do is enable it via DevTools, Something like that:

```
async function setDownload () {
  const client = await CDP({tab: 'ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser'});
  const info =  await client.send('Browser.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior : "allow", downloadPath: "/tmp/"});
  await client.close();
}
```

This is the solution some one gave in the mentioned topic. [Here is his comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c39).

Comment: This solution requires to patch Chrome, it's not a workaround. The command `Browser.setDownloadBehavior` is **not present** in Chrome v62.0.3186.0.

Comment: I jumped into the same issue a couple of months ago. Haven't found any solution until today, thanks to a dude commenting my question and pointing me here. Reading this answer makes me happy, but I truly have no clue on how to copy or adapt this code in my source.

Comment: @TheChetan thanks! interesting link, though i am developing it in java and a `chromePrefs.put("Browser.setDownloadBehavior", "allow");` would help more, if only this string was a real one and working.. ):

Comment: How would you do it in Python with selenium?

Comment: @Nihvel Are you able to address this in Java ?Can you please post the solution

Comment: @Coded9 haven't yet found the solution. I have a look at news, from time to time, yet no one posted a working one. I did see some "workarounds", haven't tried 'em, and not an "official" method.

Comment: I tried a workaround but that has given me another error
[1517577658.639][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer

Answer (score 9):

UPDATED PYTHON SOLUTION -
TESTED Mar 4, 2021 on chromedriver v88 and v89

This will allow you to click to download files in headless mode.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    # Instantiate headless driver
    chrome_options = Options()

    # Windows path
    chromedriver_location = 'C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
    # Mac path. May have to allow chromedriver developer in os system prefs
    '/Users/path/to/chromedriver'

    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    
    chrome_prefs = {"download.default_directory": r"C:\path\to\Downloads"} # (windows)
    chrome_options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location,options=chrome_options)

    # Download your file
    driver.get('https://www.mockaroo.com/')
    driver.find_element_by_id('download').click()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, only added the download path in chrome_prefs as experimental_options and did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the website that you handle returns different HTML pages for browsers, means the XPath or Id that you want maybe differently in headless browser.
Try to download pageSource in headless browser and open it as HTML page to see the Id or XPath that you want.
You can see this as c# example [How to hide FirefoxDriver (using Selenium) without findElement function error in PhantomDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233065/how-to-hide-firefoxdriver-using-selenium-without-findelement-function-error-in/45649146#45649146) .

Comment: After I get the page and I do `driver.get_screenshot_as_file('foo.png')`, I get an image of the actual thing and it looks ok. Also, the driver is able to find the button. Investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

A full working example for JavaScript with selenium-cucumber-js / selenium-webdriver:

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
const selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
const command = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/command');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

module.exports = function() {

  const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()
    .addArguments('--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--start-maximized', '--ignore-certificate-errors')
    .setUserPreferences({
      'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0, // disable download file dialog
      'download.default_directory': '/tmp/downloads', // default file download location
      "download.prompt_for_download": false,
      'download.directory_upgrade': true,
      'safebrowsing.enabled': false,
      'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true,
      'plugins.plugins_disabled': ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
    })
    .windowSize({width: 1600, height: 1200});

  const driver = new selenium.Builder()
    .withCapabilities({
      browserName: 'chrome',
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      acceptSslCerts: true,
      path: chromedriver.path
    })
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .build();

  driver.manage().window().maximize();

  driver.getSession()
    .then(session => {
      const cmd = new command.Command("SEND_COMMAND")
        .setParameter("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior")
        .setParameter("params", {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': '/tmp/downloads'});
      driver.getExecutor().defineCommand("SEND_COMMAND", "POST", `/session/${session.getId()}/chromium/send_command`);
      return driver.execute(cmd);
    });

  return driver;
};
```

The key part is:

```
  driver.getSession()
    .then(session => {
      const cmd = new command.Command("SEND_COMMAND")
        .setParameter("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior")
        .setParameter("params", {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': '/tmp/downloads'});
      driver.getExecutor().defineCommand("SEND_COMMAND", "POST", `/session/${session.getId()}/chromium/send_command`);
      return driver.execute(cmd);
    });
```

Tested with:

- Chrome 67.0.3396.99
- Chromedriver 2.36.540469
- selenium-cucumber-js 1.5.12
- selenium-webdriver 3.0.0

Comment: Thanks for posting the javascript solution. It wasn't completely obvious how to execute the command.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's redundant seeing the same thing just written in another language, but because this issue drove me crazy, I hope I'm saving someone else from the pain... so here's the C# version of [Shawn Button's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366981/2733526) (tested with headless chrome=71.0.3578.98, chromedriver=2.45.615279, platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)):

```
            var enableDownloadCommandParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "behavior", "allow" },
                { "downloadPath", downloadDirectoryPath }
            };
            var result = ((OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver)driver).ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult("Page.setDownloadBehavior", enableDownloadCommandParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the equivalent in Java, selenium, chromedriver and chrome v 71.x. The code in  is the key to allow saving of downloads
Additional jars: com.fasterxml.jackson.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\libraries\chromedriver.exe");

```
            String downloadFilepath = "C:\\Download";
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePreferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePreferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            chromePreferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
            chromePreferences.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\pathto\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe");

            //ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePreferences);
            chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");


            //HEADLESS CHROME
            **chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");**

            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePreferences);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

            **ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions);

            Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
            commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("behavior", "allow");
            params.put("downloadPath", downloadFilepath);
            commandParams.put("params", params);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
            String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));**
            try {
                httpClient.execute(request);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }**

        //Continue using the driver for automation  
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the workaround shared by @Shawn Button and using the **full path** for the 'downloadPath' parameter. Using a **relative path** did not work and give me the error.

Versions:
Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (32-bit)
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90

Comment: Please write your chrome and chrome driver versions. Major changes are being done in each releases and the workarounds can be useless.. For example https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c198

Answer (score 0):

Using: `google-chrome-stable amd64 86.0.4240.111-1`,`chromedriver 86.0.4240.22`, `selenium 3.141.0` `python 3.8.3`

Tried multiple proposed solutions, and nothing really worked for chrome headless, also my testing website opens a new blank tab and then the data is downloaded.

Finally gave up on headless and implemented [pyvirtualdisplay](https://github.com/ponty/pyvirtualdisplay/tree/1.3.2) and `xvfd` to emulate X server, something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options # and other imports
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import tempfile

url = "https://really_badly_programmed_website.org"

tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="hamster_")

driver_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver"

chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

prefs = {'download.default_directory': tmp_dir,}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

with Display(backend="xvfb",size=(1920,1080),color_depth=24) as disp:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get(url)
```

At the end everything worked and had the dowload file on the tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by upgrading to Chromium 90!  I previously had version 72-78, but I saw that it had been fixed recently:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481  so i decided to give it a shot.

So after upgrading, which took a while (home brew in MacOS is so slow...), I simply did, without setting options or anything (this is a JavaScript example):

```
await driver.findElement(By.className('download')).click();
```

And it worked! I saw the downloaded PDF in the same working folder that I had been trying to download for a long time...