# What is preventing me from downloading files in Browser window that opens when using automated testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to download a CSV file using Selenium-Webdriver in a Chrome Browser window (Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)) that opens when doing automated tests.  I am using Selenium version: 3.4

Here is the HTML:

```
<h4>
<a href="/Hardware/ExportCsv?hardId=USB" download="Drives.csv" id="excel-btn">
        <img src="../../Content/Images/excel.svg">
        Export csv file.
    </a>
</h4>
```

Neither `click()` nor using the `Actions` class work.  If I click the link with my mouse, the file is downloaded.

```
Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("excel-btn")).click();
```

```
action.moveToElement(Browser.driver.findElement(By.id("excel-btn"))).click().perform();
```

I expect the file to be downloaded.

Instead, however, the download link text is just being highlighted.

Important to note: in contrast, I can find other elements, assign them to a `WebElement` and execute Selenium actions on those elements successfully. It is just the download that is eluding me.

Comment: Can't help much without providing actual HTML of the page you are automating,meanwhile I could recommend to try clicking element by executing java script:

    public void clickWithJavaScript(WebElement element)
    {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }

Comment: Thanks @Matthewek I tried the JavascriptExecutor as well--did not work.  Should have added that attempt as well.

Comment: Possibly your browser settings are different from the settings of the browser run by selenium. Anyway, you need to provide more relevant information, if you want us to help: browser type and version, HTML code, Selenium version, ...

Comment: @Würgspaß, edited the post to reflect your points.  Thank you.

Comment: @WindSurfDude Upvoted your question. Sadly, I am not into Chrome. So I cant help you, but some other one might.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that works!  The same solution that allows you to download files in a `headless browser` applies in this case as well.  Essentially, there is a feature to prevent software from downloading files to your computer via the Chrome Browser. To get around that, you need to `.setDownloadBehavior` to allow downloading.  (Make sure to set the `Download Path` to your download directory.)

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium?rq=1); and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481) for code samples in Java, Python and C#.