# How to download a csv file from internet when there is javascript button?

Tags: python, download

I am trying to download a CSV file from morningstar using python. 
here is the link:
http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=NAB&region=aus

There is a button to "export CSV" but I can't access the link.

There is this javascript:exportKeyStat2CSV(); but  I am not sure how to find the URL of the CSV file?

I tried to download the file and get the URL to use requests/panadas to download the file but requests/panadas cant get anything.

```
import pandas as pd
URL= ("http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XASX:NAB&region=aus&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc")

df=pd.read_csv(URL) ( didnt work with pandas)


import requests

print ('Starting to Download!')


r = requests.get(URL)

filename = url.split('/')[-1]

with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(r.content)

print("Download complete!")
```

I get Requests 204 code.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the resource via Selenium with Python?

See this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725319/5198805