# Downloading a file in headless ChromeDriver with SeleniumBasic

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying to download files by clicking a button. This works fine as long as my ChromeDriver is not in headless mode. Once I tested the macro with ChromeDriver in headless mode, I realized that nothing was being downloaded. I researched the issue and found out that it was a [security measure](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481). There are [suggested work-arounds for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium), however I was not able to translate the code into VBA. I am using [SeleniumBasic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/).

What I want is to be able to download files to the `Environ("userprofile") & "\Downloads\"` folder once I click a download button, just like I do when the browser is not in headless mode. Thank you all in advance.

Notes:

- I call the driver in headless mode using `driver.AddArgument "--headless"`
- I could not provide the URL I am using as this is a long macro requiring login etc. but as far as I understand, the issue should be reproducible in any download scenario involving a headless ChromeDriver.
- I am using the most recent SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.0 and the ChromeDriver version 75.0.3770.140

Comment: you might be able to use driver.executeScript to run [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668964/6241235])  as a string you pass as arg. Though update paths and escape ". The other answer in your link I don't think can be translated.

Comment: I am not sure what that would look like :/ I am open to try it out if you could convert it into familiar syntax. I know a little about using driver.executeScript, mainly for scrolling, but in this case I am lost as to what would be the string and what would be the remaining arguments.

Comment: it would be driver.executeScript(s)   where s is the string in that answer. The string would need to be wrapped in "" meaning any inside " needs to be doubled up to escape. You would also use _ to break across lines.  Bit like you see here: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/85

Comment: based on comments under that answer you might find this won't work on later versions anyway.

Comment: I haven't been able to use the headless option for about a year and I am interested in knowing how this plays out. After my headless scripts broke, I noticed that I can't minimize an automated window or even partially cover it without interrupting browser automation.  Having an automated solution if far more important to me than having a silent automated solution so I haven't looked for a way to run headless again.  I don't even know if I would have the same problem if I moved away from Selenium and Chrome by converting to IE.  Too much time, too little reward.

Comment: You need to use ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.10 - 'Support to save file downloads in headless mode' . https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @RahulL thank you for the response. The latest version of SeleniumBasic is only compatible with v75.0.3770.140 as far as I know. I have given up on this for now, working without clientless.