# Downloading files with selenium (python3) on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu-18.04

I wrote a simple script using the user Fayçal's code from 
[Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium) the script worked on my Mac but when I went to run it on the server nothing was downloaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "/download/path/",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': "/Download/path/"}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

#navigate to advanced search
driver.get(loginUrl)
driver.find_element_by_name("login_username").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_name("login_password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

driver.get(targetUrl)
file = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/a")
file.click()
```

The script runs and does not return any errors nothing but the target path remains empty.

Comment: Is file downloaded in new tab? or downloaded directly?

Comment: It is downloaded directly.