# Selenium can't find element on Linux headless, but it can on Windows headless?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am running Selenium headless on a Linux machine, and it can't find a specific element. However, I run the same exact code on a Windows machine and it finds the element without a problem. I have the latest version of the driver on my Linux machine. Any ideas how to fix this?

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                     'Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36')
with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnhome").click()
    video = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "video"))).get_attribute("src")
```

The problem element is the video element. I have increased the wait time to 2 minutes as well, just for debugging. It works fine on Windows headless, but can't find it on Linux headless.

Thanks

Comment: One quick thing you can do to check is to disable headless, let the browser be visible and and see where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Instead of  `presence_of_element_located` can you try with `element_to_be_clickable` or `visibility_of_element_located` and update us if that helps ?

Comment: I second @curisepandey. presence of element gets a green even if the element is in background and not necessarily get visible and clickable in DOM.

Comment: @AnandGautam Unfortunately the Linux system is a non-GUI system, so I can't run it unless it is headless

Comment: @cruisepandey Nope, neither worked

Comment: Take screenshot or print page source after `driver.get(url)` to be sure, you've not redirected to some other page, e.g. detected as a bot or got some security alert.

Comment: Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672/7058266 should help you get around your issue. I put all the details you need in the longer answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

2023 Update: I'm revising my original answer to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266 as a better solution. There's a new Chrome headless mode that gets the same results as regular Chrome:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

---

The solution for this involves using https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay in order to simulate a headed display in a headless environment such as Linux. (This can help you get around issues that might only appear when loading a website with a headless browser.) The virtual display uses `Xvfb`, and there's actually a very popular Stack Overflow solution here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300672

Here's a summary of the previous solution for your situation:

To install:

```bash
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

And here's how to use it in your Python code:

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
# display is active / Run your selenium code
# ----------
display.stop()
# display is stopped
```

After putting it all together with your code, it will look something like this:

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
# ...
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                     'Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36')
with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnhome").click()
    video = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "video"))).get_attribute("src")
# ...
display.stop()
```

(Make modifications as necessary, such as the screen resolution, etc.)

There are some Selenium Python frameworks that already have the virtual display built-in (such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), which activates the virtual display via an added `pytest` command-line arg: `--xvfb`.) Each framework that has the feature built-in may do things a bit differently.

Comment: Just be sure NOT to run Chrome in headless mode if you use this solution. The virtual display should allow you to run a regular headed Chrome in the headless environment.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks