# Selenium Chrome driver headless mode not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

My code worked perfectly until yesterday when I updated *Google Chrome* to version **110.0.5481.77**. Now it's not working in headless mode:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I even tried adding `options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,700")` but still not working. Although if I remove the headless option it again works correctly!

Comment: try this [Chrome driver of selenium in headless mode not finding any element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77745928/chrome-driver-of-selenium-in-headless-mode-not-finding-any-element/77806896#77806896)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Accroding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium/73840130#73840130) and [Google Chrome release notes](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408#hdlssMod110) you should add the headless mode option like below:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

and no need to specify the *window size*

Comment: But it seems by default uses a small resolution.
It seems to be something like 800x600.

Comment: @PauloOliveira My use case is well served by the default, but I think you can use the `options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,700")` to justify that. If that doesn't solve feel free to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: Does not work for me on 112 stable or 113 beta.

Comment: @PauloOliveira I've got no idea, if you could figure it out post an answer.

Comment: This works with Chrome 114 and Chromium 114. Nothing else worked for me. Strange thing is, that for other sites I can use the options.add_argument("--headless") version, but for one specific site I can't

Comment: Do you know why it's now working for Kayak? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093600/option-add-argument-headless-doesnt-work-for-chrome-122-when-scrap-kayak

Comment: @ErikJohnsson unfortunately I'm not aware of the inner workings nor the specific site you are scraping, but I guess seeing the `Selenium` logs may help you identify the problem. It's easy to set that up, I can't say off the top of my head, but with a quick search you can do that.