# Chrome "--headless=new" mode does not allow to apply "--window-size" option

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

When new chrome headless mode is used the "--windows-size=width,height" argument doesn't work.
For example:
"--headless=new",
"--window-size=1920,1080"
Running tests with these arguments produces strange size screenshots: 1028x653 px

But with the old headless mode:
"--headless",
"--window-size=1920,1080"
the screenshots size is OK: 1920x1080 px.

I can't use old mode, because the files downloading is not working in it anymore, here is the post about it, where using the new headless mode is suggest as a solution: [Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45631715/21205827)

Comment: I have found a solution. The problem with downloads in old headless mode (“headless=old”) was caused by me deleting the "download.default_directory" value from "userProfilePreferences" object in driver options in config file.

Comment: I have forgotten that this is necessary for the downloads to works with old headless mode.
Bringing this value back fixed the problem with downloading files.
So now I don’t need to care about the problem with window-size in new version headless mode (“headless=new”). At least the old headless mode will not be completely removed from chrome (I hove it will not happen for a long time )

Comment: No, that doesn't help actually. It was OK on ver 109. After upgrading the Chrome to 110 version, the problem returns.

Comment: This is a bug being fixed in Chrome. You can see the status of the fix and the reasons here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1416398

Answer (score 4):

We came accross the same issue. Until the bug is solved, our workaroud is zooming out.  We added argument *force-device-scale-factor=0.75*.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact problem! Luckily I found a workaround! For java instead of ***--window-size=1920,1080*** I did:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

I also removed screen maximisation and it worked for me!

Please try above code or it's equivalent for the language you are using selenium with!

P.S.: I'm running selenium with xvfb! so if you have issues with screen size, you might look into that

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help (C# .Net, Azure Windows agents)

Comment: there is some ongoing issues I guess. They might fix that in newer chrome builds! you can try reducing scaling by option.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.5");

Comment: 0.5 scale factor is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your tests with a CI-Tool like Jenkins?
I see a similar behavior (messing up the screen size) only with a central run on Jenkins, like always..local it works.
If so I think it has to do with the system user the test is executed through a jenkins agent.

Comment: I am running tests locally and on Azure windows machines agents. Locally the difference is not so big, but still presents.

Comment: 1904 x 890 - that is actual window-size for local run. And it perfectly OK with old headless mode. Except for the files downloads, which don't work at all ((