# After updating chromium from 108 to 110: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium to access a service that require login. I login one time then the login in data saved into user data, a dir that I specify as following:

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=%s" % self.user_dir)
```

Everything was okay until I updated the system (Ubuntu server). Chromium was updated from 108 to 110. The first issue i faced that I need to update the ChromeDriver to 110.0.5481.77.

Now, when I use Selenium as usual, it took long time until I get the following error:

```
File "/home/user/bots/teleBots/app/wa.py", line 49, in __init__
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver, options=self.chrome_options,
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/ak_env_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

I searched for solution and most of them suggest using the option:

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

and others:

```
        chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```

But nothing works for me until I removed the user dir option:

```
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=%s" % self.user_dir)
```

It works for me but I have to log in everytime I run the script.

How can I solved this issue?

Is there anyway to downgrade chromium browser to 108? (I need deb file for ubuntu)

Or anyway to keep login active other than using user-data-dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a breaking change of headless in Chrome 109. Change your argument `--headless` or `--headless=chrome` to `--headless=new`

Based on this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130

Comment: I used `--headless=new` and now I can use the new driver. Thanks. Accepted Answer for now.

Comment: Even though this solves the issue, a lot of issues are still facing me using the new update. I went back to downgrading. No need for this crazy update :/

Comment: Yes, there is also a bug in chromedriver (fixed in version 111) when using both --headless and --user-data-dir. You are right. It is a terrible time to update.

Answer (score 1):

I was lucky to find in my downloads dir an old version of google chrome (108).

I installed it using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then, I downloaded the right version of the chrome driver from:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

and yes! Life back to it usual. Could be a bug in the new chrome driver. Hopefully we can find other solutions for version 110

Comment: New chromedriver almost always has random issues. I disable chrome auto update and only update chrome/chromedriver once in a while because of it.

Comment: can you share the deb package of chrome 108, I updated yesterday and I'm having a lot of new bugs

Comment: @SantiagoFuentes Sure, but where should I upload it for you?

Comment: @SantiagoFuentes this is it https://www.mediafire.com/file/cu4xv911qqp514q/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb/file

Comment: @SantiagoFuentes The accepted answer will allow you to use the new version without downgrade

Comment: Again I went back to this solution since other issues came with the new update.

Comment: I used the new headless flag before I downgraded to 108, it worked but then a lot of new bugs start to appear, that's why I ended downgrading