# When running selenium-grid, --download-paths argument is being ignored

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm running the Selenium-grid standalone server on Ubuntu using this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.8.0.jar standalone --downloads-path /etc/selenoid/download
```

but when the driver downloads files they are being downloaded to the path of "/home/my_username/" which is where I'm running the server from the command line at. So this looks like the default download path, which is ignoring my --downloads-path argument.

My server does have an /etc/selenoid/download directory as well and the my_username:myusername owns that directory. So selenium Grid should have permissions to create/delete/edit files/folders within that directory.

I'm also setting the download.default_directory when setting the options of the driver.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('download.default_directory=/etc/selenoid/download')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
                        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,
                        "download.default_directory": "/etc/selenoid/download",
                        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                        "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
                        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
                        "plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
                        })

webdriver.Remote(command_executor=grid_uri, options=options)
```

I'm lost at the moment, when I run this on my local mac machine it works as expected, but not on my linux server.

Comment: If the WebDriver test and Selenium Grid on the same host then you can see what download path has been phycially set by your `RemoteWebDriver` by breakpointing the test when a Chrome instance is created. In the resulting Chrome browser (being controlled by `RemoteWebDriver`) open 'Settings -> Downloads' and check the path. `--downloads-path` will only used by the GET `/session/<sessionId>/se/file` endpoint to retrieve the downloaded file from the remote Node session.

Comment: This might also be useful: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5292

Comment: I think you need an absolute path there... and make sure the path is valid and that the browser has permission to write to it, or it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I Discovered that when running Chrome headless it will not use the `download.default_directory` argument unless you run using the new headless mode, like so:

```
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

Here's the link to the stack overflow answer that solved the root of my problem:
[Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium/73840130#73840130)