# Link not picking in headless mode #python #selenium #automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

While using python selenium automation not able to select a link while code is running in headless mode...but when headless mode is disabled it is working and it is picking the link properly..

I tried changing windows size and checked versions also..i expect the code to pick the link even in headless mode (in background)

Comment: Some websites can and will try to prevent scraping  - detecting if the browser is "headless" is one of those  ways.

Comment: you can look into `undetected chrome-driver`. It might solve the issue.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: Use the new headless mode, which works exactly like the regular headed mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266