# Selenide cannot download file with Chrome Driver 111 in headless mode

Tags: java, download, selenium-chromedriver, headless, selenide

I have a test that need to download file from a web by clicking on a button.

Test is able to pass when in **non-headless** mode.

However when I run it in **headless** it fails with timeout to download file.

Here are some details:

- Selenide version: 5.25.0
- Chrome Driver version: 111.0.5563.64

My configurations:

- non-headless run:

```
Configuration.timeout = 20000;
Configuration.fileDownload = FOLDER;
```

- headless run:

```
Configuration.headless = true;
Configuration.timeout = 20000;
Configuration.fileDownload = FOLDER;
```

Other options are as default, like downloads folder `build/downloads` and rest of them.

My Selenide code to download file:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    public String downloadFile() {
        return downloadButton.download(10000, withExtension("pdf")).getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

The button element itself:

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedSecondary" tabindex="0" type="button" test-id="download-button">
    <span class="MuiButton-label">Download</span>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
```

Logs:

- non-headless:

```
13:20:09.959 INFO com.codeborne.selenide.impl.DownloadFileToFolder - Downloaded 1 files:
  #1  {root}\build\downloads\1678792759151_10256_1\109fc116-cc8b-42ba-9d7b-20733276bf64.pdf
```

- headless:

```
13:07:19.760 INFO com.codeborne.selenide.impl.DownloadFileToFolder - Downloaded 0 files:
13:07:19.778 INFO com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WindowsCloser - File has been opened in a new window, let's close 1 new windows
13:07:19.778 INFO com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WindowsCloser - Let's close B0C0F608D49BC5C008986B2B7AB210C5
```

I've tried all of the solutions described in similar topics with adding a lot of different combinations of chrome options but no luck.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've found a reason.

Recently Chromium drivers changed their headless mode configs.

You can find more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/11830541

Exactly my problem was that I used old Selenide version that uses the legacy `--headless` arg while creating headless options, however it must be `--headless-new` since Chrome 109.

To make this work with older versions of Selenide I used a workaround like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--headless=new");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-background-networking");
options.addArguments("--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess");
options.addArguments("--disable-background-timer-throttling");
options.addArguments("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows");
options.addArguments("--disable-breakpad");
options.addArguments("--disable-client-side-phishing-detection");
options.addArguments("--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages");
options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
options.addArguments("--disable-features=TranslateUI,ChromePDF");
options.addArguments("--disable-hang-monitor");
options.addArguments("--disable-ipc-flooding-protection");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-prompt-on-repost");
options.addArguments("--disable-renderer-backgrounding");
options.addArguments("--disable-sync");
options.addArguments("--force-color-profile=srgb");
options.addArguments("--metrics-recording-only");
options.addArguments("--no-first-run");
options.addArguments("--password-store=basic");
options.addArguments("--use-mock-keychain");
options.addArguments("--hide-scrollbars");
options.addArguments("--mute-audio");

Configuration.browserCapabilities = options;
```

Other options from `--headless=new` arg are the same that Selenide adds under-the-hood when you use `Configuration.headless = true;`

**NOTE:**
It is better to upgrade Selenide dependency to newer version where this Chromium Driver change is handled properly: https://github.com/selenide/selenide/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#6120-released-24022023

Comment: Why do you need to many arguments.

Comment: I don't need most of them obviously, however this is what Selenide adds under the hood. So this is just to make sure it runs ok. Of course, this can be reduced depending on your need.