# Selenium Webdriver Headless Mode shows blank page selenium web element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Observation:
1.When (chrome_linux_headless) is enabled, After click on web element it is showing blank page  in selenium automation.
2.And if I disable the Headless mode(chrome driver), everything works fine in selenium automation.

Browser details:
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build) (64-bit)

We have tried:
1.driver.navigate().refresh();

2.Get userAgent of browser first:
String userAgent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;");

System.setProperty("useragent",userAgent);

//Add it to browser option as below
options.addArguments("--user-agent="+System.getProperty("useragent"));

Comment: _When (chrome_linux_headless) is enabled_: How are you enabling them? What are the other configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the newer Chrome headless mode: `--headless=new`, instead of the old one (`--headless`). The new one makes headless mode work the same way as regular Chrome:

```java
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
```

For details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266

Comment: Thank you!! It is working for us for hedaless_chrome and headless_chrome_linux