# Selenium automation not working when active in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, deployment, headless

I have following code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service; 
import undetected_chromedriver as uc;
import time;
import os; 

chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions();
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-automation"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless"); 
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk"); 

chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN");
service = Service(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"));
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=service);
driver.get('https://www.google.com/');

print(driver.page_source);

x = 1884
y = 28 


time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script(f'document.elementFromPoint({x}, {y}).click();');
```

This is just a silly example, but imagine that this is indeed my intended use, when active in headless mode it just doesn't execute following part of program

```
driver.execute_script(f'document.elementFromPoint({x}, {y}).click();');
```

however, just comment out the line

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless");
```

that everything works. Remembering that there are no error messages, because this is an error on the tests I did, and I noticed that it does not process the scripts when in headless mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replacing with:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/