# Why does this selenium script work for non-headless, but when I switch this to headless, it doesn't work?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

This script is supposed to go into booking.com and grab the first price of the waldorf astoria Las Vegas hotel. It completely works for when I'm opening a browser, but doesn't work after switching to headless mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import translateXMLfile
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class BookingAutomation:
    WINDOW_SIZE = "1200,900"
    HEADLESS = True
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def setup_driver(self):
        
        opts = Options()  # Use webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        if self.HEADLESS:
            opts.add_argument('--headless') #runs a headless search
            
        opts.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % self.WINDOW_SIZE)
        
        # self.driver =webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(opts)

        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get('https://www.booking.com') #go to the booking.com url
        time.sleep(2)
        
        close_popup = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Dismiss sign-in info.']") #close the popup that pops when you first enter the website
        close_popup.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        

    def select_dates(self):
        
        search = self.driver.find_element(By.ID,':re:') #find the search bar
        search.send_keys(translateXMLfile.name) # enter the waldorf astoria
        
        time.sleep(3)
        

        date = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="date-display-field-end"]')
        date.click() #find the calendar and click it

        next_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                               "button[class='a83ed08757 c21c56c305 f38b6daa18 d691166b09 f671049264 deab83296e f4552b6561 dc72a8413c f073249358']") #go into the next month
        next_button.click() #click the next button

        inday = translateXMLfile.iday #insert the before and after days
        oday = translateXMLfile.oday

        formatted_inday = f"{inday:02d}"
        formatted_oday = f"{oday:02d}"

        date_element_xpath = f"//span[contains(@aria-label, '{formatted_inday} October 2023')]"
        date_element_xpatho = f"//span[contains(@aria-label, '{formatted_oday} October 2023')]"

        checkin_date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, date_element_xpath)
        checkout_date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, date_element_xpatho)

        checkin_date.click()
        checkout_date.click()
        
        *************search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) #click enter after entering the search and the date
        
        
       Inside these stars are where I believe my issue lies
        
    def search_hotels(self):
        self.driver.save_screenshot('2nd test.png') #this displays the image, somehow deleting what I wrote and the dates I've put in after I click enter*********************************************

        first_result = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='c82435a4b8 a178069f51 a6ae3c2b40 a18aeea94d d794b7a0f7 f53e278e95 da89aeb942 c12ee2f811'] div[class='d20f4628d0'] div[class='b978843432'] div[class='aca0ade214 aaf30230d9 cd2e7d62b0 f996d8c258'] div div[class='aca0ade214 c9835feea9 c2931f4182 d79e71457a d14b211b4f'] div[class='aaee4e7cd3 e7a57abb1e'] div[class='aca0ade214 a5f1aae5b2 cd2e7d62b0'] div div[class='f6431b446c a23c043802']") ****** this fails to grab for some reason, but only in headless mode
        
        first_result.click()
        
        time.sleep(2)
        
    def check_prices(self):
        handles = []
        handles = self.driver.window_handles
        if len(handles)>1:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])

        time.sleep(10)

        
       
        
        first_price = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@class,'js-rt-block-row e2e-hprt-table-row hprt-table-cheapest-block hprt-table-cheapest-block-fix js-hprt-table-cheapest-block')]//div//div//span[@class='prco-valign-middle-helper'][normalize-space()='$2,177']")  # Replace with your XPath
        print(first_price.text)
        time.sleep(5)
        
    def close_driver(self):
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    booking_automation = BookingAutomation(driver)
    booking_automation.setup_driver()
    # booking_automation.check_height()
    booking_automation.select_dates()
    booking_automation.search_hotels()
    # booking_automation.check_prices()
    
    booking_automation.close_driver()
```

I have tried putting the date before the search, then clicking the enter button, I tried pressing enter on the keyboard, I tried waiting before clicking the button as well as the keyboard. If there is anyone that has the slightest clue how to solve this I would really appreciate it. I've been banging my head on this for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using Chrome's old headless mode, which works differently from regular Chrome. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266

If you want headless Chrome to work the same as regular headed Chrome, then change this:

```py
opts.add_argument("--headless")
```

To this:

```py
opts.add_argument("--headless=new")
```