Chrome 129 Headless shows blank window

Today, I updated the Chrome browser to the latest version (129). After the update, running Chrome in headless mode produces an unusual result: a blank white window appears, matching the size of the browser.
I was using Puppeteer and Selenium with Chrome 129 on Windows.
Why did this blank window start appearing? Is this a bug with Chrome 129?
Test Result:




Chrome128
Chrome129
Chrome130




Puppeteer(v23.4.0)
O
X
O


Selenium(v4.0)
O
X
O


Playwright(v1.47.1)
O
X
O



Update:
MacOS, Linux no problem.

We don't have support for 129 yet. Upstream change in puppeteer might come soon.

Same problem for me since morning after replacing chromedriver with 129, updated Selenium lib and used headless=new but it won't fix it. it must be a bug.

Facing similar issue since the time I update my chrome browser to 129. Also, I update the headless flag to --headless=new as per this link: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

Bug tickets were filed for this in the Chromium project:

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/367755364
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/359921643

This affects Windows users of headless Chromium 129, where Chromium changed the default headless mode from the old one (--headless=old) to the new one (--headless=new).
If you read all the Stack Overflow comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266, you'll find that the old headless mode is being retired this year. (It's already not the default headless mode anymore.)
Here's my temporary fix for the bug (when using Chrome's new headless mode):

--window-position=-2400,-2400

options.add_argument("--window-position=-2400,-2400")

(I moved the window far off-screen so that it's not seen.)
Or, for now, you can switch back to the old headless mode (--headless=old), but that's being retired soon, and lacks the features of the new headless mode. The PR with the fix has already been merged: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/5789117 (but you might not see that until Chrome 130).

I tried "--headless=new" option. but it shows same error.
chrome128 and chrome130 have no problem. only chrome129 has an error.

Use --window-position=-2400,-2400 for now. The Chromium Team hasn't patched the bug in 129 yet.

options.add_argument("--headless=old")


Testing with chrome: Version 129.0.6668.59 (Official Build) (64-bit), this works well!

This worked for me using chome 129.0.6668.58 and selenium 4.7.2. But what we should do when the old version gets depricated this year?

After struggling for hours on Chrome 129, the answer by Filipe Branquinho works for me:
options.add_argument("--headless=old")

However, this is likely just a temporary fix and it would be better to simply move to a different Chrome version that's unaffected by the bug.

Try the New Headless Mode Flag: --headless=new
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: true,  // Use legacy headless mode
args: ['--headless=chrome', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox']
});
Possible Causes:
Chrome 129 Headless Mode Behavior Change:
Chrome's headless mode has undergone significant changes in recent versions. Since Chrome 109, there's a new mode called headless mode v2 (--headless=new), which changes how rendering is handled. It's possible that Chrome 129 has either enforced or further modified this behavior.
Missing or Incorrect Flags:
The blank white window often indicates that the correct flags for headless mode are not being passed. Headless mode requires specific flags to ensure the browser runs correctly without rendering a visible window.
Rendering Issues with Puppeteer/Selenium:
Puppeteer and Selenium may need updates to handle the changes in Chrome 129's headless mode. If they are not up to date or properly configured for the latest Chrome version, rendering may fail, resulting in a blank window.
Driver or Compatibility Issues:
The ChromeDriver used by Selenium and Puppeteer might not be fully compatible with Chrome 129, especially if the headless mode behavior has changed. Ensuring that ChromeDriver is updated to the latest version that matches Chrome 129 is crucial.

it is not new + problem persists regardless.
