# How to use chrome webdriver in selenium to download files in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Based on the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824124/how-to-change-file-download-location-in-webdriver-while-using-chrome-driver-fire) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698843/how-do-i-pass-options-to-the-selenium-chrome-driver-using-python) I am trying to use a chrome webdriver in selenium to be able to download a file. Here is the code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("download.prompt_for_download", "false")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("download.default_directory", "/tmp")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But this alone results in the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: unrecognized chrome option: download.default_directory
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 4.10.0-37-generic x86_64)
```

So how to fix this? Do I have to use this 'capability' thing? If so, how exactly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this. Executed on windows

([How to control the download of files with Selenium Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

Comment: Yes thats it... I used the options in the wrong way. Hard to get the right documentation. Is that somewhere documented, except SO...?

Comment: if you would care to explain what is the purpose of setting safe browsing and what is directory upgrade please?

Comment: Ensure `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)` and not just `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reliable... I've started getting download prompt to save the file.. would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Best guess; this doesn't work if the employer managed chrome does not let me set these settings manually. :(

Comment: @Alex - You can find good documentation [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#condition-13)

Comment: @Dkyc I've found the best documentation on available prefs and what they're supposed to do to be the Chromium source code, under chrome/common/pref_names.cc.  E.g., for `directory_upgrade`:

// Boolean that records if the download directory was changed by an
// upgrade a unsafe location to a safe location.
const char kDownloadDirUpgraded[] = "download.directory_upgrade";

So I'd say it shouldn't be useful.

Comment: And indeed, only `download.default_directory` and `download.prompt_for_download` are required, as of Chromium 97.

Comment: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/common/pref_names.cc also relevant

Comment: Just to say that it works well on linux also

Answer (score 5):

Some tips:

1. **chromium and chromedriver should have same version.**

   Typically chromium package should have chromedriver inside, you can find it in the install dir. If you are using ubuntu/debian, execute `dpkg -L chromium-chromedriver`.
2. **Have a correct Chrome preference config.**

   as Satish said, use `options.add_experimental_option("prefs", ...)` to config selenium+chrome. But sometimes the config may change by time. **The beset way to get newest and workable prefs is to check it in the chromium config dir.**
   For example,

   - Launch a chromium in Xorg desktop
   - Change settings in menu
   - Quit chromium
   - Find out the real settings in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`
   - Read it, pick out the exact options you need.

In my case, the code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.gpu = False
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory" : "/data/books/chrome/",
    'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 2,
    })

desired = options.to_capabilities()
desired['loggingPrefs'] = { 'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired)
```

Comment: where is chromium config dir?

Answer (score 5):

I think that the easiest way to save arbitrary file (i.e. image) using WebDriver is to execute JavaScript which will save file. No configuration required at all!

I use this library [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save a file with desired name with ease.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

FILE_SAVER_MIN_JS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/dist/FileSaver.min.js"

file_saver_min_js = requests.get(FILE_SAVER_MIN_JS_URL).content

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

# Execute FileSaver.js in page's context
driver.execute_script(file_saver_min_js)

# Now you can use saveAs() function
download_script = f'''
    return fetch('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf',
        {{
            "credentials": "same-origin",
            "headers": {{"accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"}},
            "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
            "body": null,
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": "cors"
        }}
    ).then(resp => {{
        return resp.blob();
    }}).then(blob => {{
        saveAs(blob, 'stackoverflow_logo.svg');
    }});
    '''

driver.execute_script(download_script)
# Done! Your browser has saved an SVG image!
```

Comment: To bypass repeating downloading file warnings or WebDriver Server (great for docker), use `driver.execute_script return readAsDataURL the with FileReader`

Answer (score 2):

for chrome in mac os, the download.defaultdirectory did not work for me and fortunately **savefile.default_directory** works.

```
prefs = {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(settings),
    "savefile.default_directory": "/Users/creative/python-apps",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.safebrowsing.enabled": True
}
```

Comment: Only `download.default_directory` and `download.prompt_for_download` are required, as of Chromium 97.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons you can't set "download.default_directory" may be that you have a system variable **XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR** in file **~/.config/user-dirs.dirs**

You can remove variable form that file or, you can set it to whatever you like before running your program.

I was looking for a solution for two days...

My SW set:

- Ubuntu bionic, 18.04.5 LTS
- chromedriver.86.0.4240.22.lin64
- Python 3.9
- selenium 3.141.0
- splinter 0.14.0

Answer (score 0):

From your exception, you are using `chromedriver=2.24.417424`.

What are the versions of Selenium and Chrome browser that are you using?

I tried the following code with:

- Selenium 3.6.0
- chromedriver 2.33
- Google Chrome 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

And it works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

download_dir = "/pathToDownloadDir"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": download_dir ,
               "directory_upgrade": True,
               "safebrowsing.enabled": True }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path=r'/pathTo/chromedriver')

driver.get("urlFileToDownload");
```

Make sure you are using a browser that is supported by your chromedriver (from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt), should be `Chrome v52-54`).

Answer (score -2):

Can't you use `requests` lib?

If so, here's an example:

```py
import re
import requests

urls = [ '...' ]

for url in urls:
  # verify = False ==> for HTTPS requests without SSL certificates
  r = requests.get( url, allow_redirects = True, verify = False )

  cd = r.headers.get( 'content-disposition' )
  fa = re.findall( 'filename=(.+)', cd )

  if len( fa ) == 0:
    print( f'Error message: {link}' )
    continue

  filename = fa[ 0 ]

  f = open( os.path.join( 'desired_path', filename ), 'wb' )
  f.write( r.content )
  f.close()
```