# How to set options in Selenium Safari with python? I want to make it undetectable and deactivate navigator flag etc

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

The title says it all.
I am using selenium with python and safari as a browser since Chromedriver is crashing. I need the safari browser to be undetectable and want to be able to set a proxy and disable the navigator flag and other things that make it detectable that I am using a bot.
Thanks for your help!
Below in the code are just examples of what I need as options not the code I think is correct for Safari would be nice if you would tell me!

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Safari()
#PROXY_HOST = "12.12.12.123"
#PROXY_PORT = "1234"
#profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
#profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
#profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
import time
import random
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchWindowException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
#options.add_argument('--proxy-server=176.9.75.42:1080')

options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36')
# another way to set profile is the below (which takes precedence if both variants are used
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=c:\\temp\\profile6')

# just some options passing in to skip annoying popups
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
```

Comment: On which site are you getting detected?

Comment: notebooksbilliger.de they sell gpus and other computer stuff. With undetected chromedriver which I use for chrome I don't get detected.

Comment: Update the question with the error/blocking message you are seeing.

Comment: I would mirror this answer swapping out chrome with safari https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698844/495157