# How to use chrome 'Hardware acceleration' and 'webgl' at Ubuntu?

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, command-line-interface

Ubuntu version : 18.04.5 and without gui
chrome version : 110.0.5481.177
I want : Using chrome to crawling with Selenium(python)
But, If I crawl to the site where I have to crawl, An error message occurs like below

> Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card.
> For more help, please click this link.
> Check out some of the following links to learn more about WebGL and to find more web applications using WebGL.
>
> WebGL Wiki
> Want more information about WebGL?
>
> khronos.org/webgl
> Hosted by Digital Ocean

And, When I approach chrome://gpu through the selenium, the following error message appears.

> Graphics Feature Status
> Canvas: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
> Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
> Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
> OpenGL: Disabled
> Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> Raw Draw: Disabled
> Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> Video Encode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
> Vulkan: Disabled
> WebGL: Disabled
> WebGL2: Disabled
> WebGPU: Disabled
> Problems Detected
> WebGPU has been disabled via blocklist or the command line.
> Disabled Features: webgpu
> Accelerated video encode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
> Disabled Features: video_encode
> Gpu compositing has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. The browser will fall back to software compositing and hardware acceleration will be unavailable.
> Disabled Features: gpu_compositing
> Version Information
> Data exported
> 2023-03-07T05:13:27.125Z
> Chrome version
> HeadlessChrome/110.0.5481.177
> Operating system
> Linux 4.15.0-163-generic
> Software rendering list URL
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f34f7ab2d4ca4ad498ef42aeba4f4eb2c1392d63/gpu/config/software_rendering_list.json
> ...

After observing the above two error messages, I think it is a 'Hardware acceleration' and 'webgl' problem.

So, I have tried to enable 'Hardware acceleration' and 'webgl' several times, but it does not work. Below is the method I tried.

`vi /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
after
edit
from `Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-stable %U`
to `Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-stable -–ignore-gpu-blacklist –-enable-webgl -–flag-switches-begin –flag-switches-end %U` etc..
(I think it might not have been applied because I don't know how to restart Chrome in a Linux environment.)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your arguments get passed correctly, try using the following script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("-–ignore-gpu-blacklist")
options.add_argument("–-enable-webgl")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

If this still doesn't work, feel free to comment, and I'll edit my answer.

[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12698844/20443541)

Comment: Thank you for comment kali.
But, I already try that..
I think 'hardware acceleration' problem.

Comment: Did you try with adding `--disable-gpu`  (additional to my code above, edited) ? This should make it use software rendering then.

Comment: Also, are you running on headless? And if yes, what code do you use to do so?

Comment: `--headless`, `--no-sandbox`, `--use-gl=egl`, `--enable-gpu-rasterization` etc.. and your advice. But, it dont change